# Numerical estimates on a given functional

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, complex, numerical-value

Consider the following functional :

$$
I(x,s) =\int_0^\infty\mathrm dy \frac{F(x + \mathrm iy, s) − F(x −\mathrm iy, s)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1},
$$
where $ F(z, s) = \dfrac{\sinh(\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)])}{z^s} $.

Let us restrict $s\in[0,1]$

In Mathematica

```
f[z_, s_] = Sinh(Sin[πGamma[z]/2z]^2)/z^s; 
II[x_, s_] := Integrate[(f[x + I y, s] - f[x - I y, s])/(Exp[2 Pi y] - 1), 
             {y, 0,Infinity}]
```

> > Can we get sharp numerical asymptotic of $I(x)$ as as $x\rightarrow \infty$?
> >
> > Also, can we get quantitative upper and lower bound estimations on the functional ?

Comment: you have syntax errors in your code. You could try `AsymptoticIntegrate` and see if it helps with this.

Comment: @yarchik  notice the $\sinh$ in this question

Comment: Please open this question , they are mistaken by the extra $\sinh$ in the question .